# Apple comes frameworks causing memory leaks is there is any solution?

Tags: avfoundation, coreml

App is using AVFoundations AVCapture for camera and core Ml for image classification, But when I put app on instruments , it is showing lot of leaks coming from apple apis, Is there is any fixes for the same ? You can see snap from leaks tool from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/166ta.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

None of those leaks are terribly bad IMO, on the order of a few bytes, and likely are caused by memory management tricks the instrument doesn't catch are actually safe.  Also they dont appear to re-occur often from what I can tell.

You'll find you tend some of those regardless of what you do on your app side, Apple classes might instantiate singletons, or have some small underlying one off leaks on occasion, but generally speaking nothing that jeopardizes the long term memory management of your apps.

Be more concerned about memory leaks you that involve your own code paths, where you can trace an allocation to a class or method you own, which implies you are not handling vended objects from Apple APIs correctly.

Comment: Only thing I can think of with limited understanding / context, is maybe there's a thread being evoked without an autorelease pool or runloop? If you are manually evoking / controlling threads - depending on what infrastructure you use from Apple you likely need a runloop and an autorelease pool for each thread.